# Best way to use Firebase Remote Config to whitelist users for feature flags?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm writing an Android app in React Native and starting to set up dynamic configuration via Firebase Remote Config.

A new feature's lifecycle is like:

1. Enable the feature only for the engineer writing it.
2. Enable for a small group of engineers/QA'ers. The members of this group can be different for each new feature. I.e. each new feature should be able to whitelist different users.
3. Enable for a wider group of testers
4. Gradually enable the feature for all users

Also, the app doesn't have email addresses or other user identifiers. So we would whitelist by device IDs.

Some flags may have integer or string values instead of boolean.

To accomplish this with Firebase Remote Config, I thought of 2 approaches

**Approach 1**: Follow [firebase doc advice](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-cases#test_new_functionality_on_a_limited_testing_group) and create a user property marking users as testers.

1. Create config values `qa_device_ids=[1,2,3], feat1_tester_device_ids=[4,5]`
2. App fetches config and sets user property `qa_devices` and `feat1_devices`

```
// 1) Fetch config to find the list of tester device IDs
Config = fetchConfig();
qa_devices = config.getValue(“qa_devices”)
feat1_devices = config.getValue(“feat1_devices”)

// 2) set the property is_qa
setUserProperty(“is_qa”, getDeviceId() in qa_devices)
setUserProperty(“is_feat1_tester”, getDeviceId() in feat1_devices)

// 3) Now that user properties have been set, re-fetch config values
Config = fetchConfig();
if (config.getValue("enable_feat1")) ...
```

Problems:

- Need to fetch config twice.
- We can only have 25 feature whitelists because an app can only have 25 user properties.
- Maintenance cost: Whenever creating a new feature flag, engineer must update config-reading code to call `setUserProperty(is_newfeat_tester, getDeviceID in newfeat_devices)`.

**Approach 2**: Use device_id as a user property.

1. Store `device_id` as a user property.
2. Create a condition `is_qa` which is true when user property `device_id` is in the QA whitetlist.
3. Config parameters can enable or disable features based on `is_qa` and also `device_id`. This way, each feature can whitelist different users.

Problem:  "[When you set user properties, be sure to never include personally identifiable information](https://screenshot.googleplex.com/27sKWU7rD62)". This approach includes PII (device ID) as a user property. It does seem overkill to store all device IDs when we actually only need to check whitelisted ones.

One could think of more approaches by hacking the config setup, etc. But this seems like a common problem. How do people usually do feature rollout using Firebase Remote Config? Or is Firebase Remote Config not appropriate for this use case?

Comment: It sounds like you actually want dedicated dev/qa environments for inhouse testing.  You usually use separate projects for that, rather than trying to put it all in the same project using conditionals in code. https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#support_different_environments

Comment: I have more features than environments though. I might have independent sets of users whitelisted for 8 different features, but I don't want 8! environments.

Comment: I'm not saying you should use a new environment for every feature.  I'm just suggesting you should have different projects to separate dev from qa from production.  You will find this extremely valuable so that you don't accidentally make changes to production while you're messing around in development.